# How to use an excel vba loop with a database query connection within?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, excel

I I'm trying to perform a loop over a variable range of cells.
A query is then run with varibles relating to the cell text.
It appears to be looping through the cells but the error lies within sql because the object is already open. I have tried to close all connections before hand but get the same error as it moves to the next cell.

```
Dim cell as range
dim rng as range
set rng = range("D9:D" & ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For each cell in rng.Cells
cell.activate

Dim CELL2 as Variant
CELL2 = Activecell

dim cnn as new adodb.connection
dim rst as new adodb.recordset
dim ConnectionString as string
dim StrQuery1 as string
dim PathID as variant

ConnectionString = ' I have inserted relevant data here'


dim xConnect as object
for each xConnect in ActiveWorkbook.Connections
xConnect.delete
Next xConnect

cnn.Open ConnectionString
cnn.CommanTimeout = 900

StrQuery1 = "Declare @DocID int Select @DocId = DocumentID from Documents where Left(Filename,10) = '" & CELL2 "'Right(Filename,6) = 'SLDDRW' Declare @PrjId int Select @PrjId = ProjectID from DocumentsinProjects where DocumentId = @DocId Select Path from Projects where ProjectID = @PrjId

rst.open StrQuery1, cnn

PathID = rst!Path

Msgbox (CELL2)
Msgbox (PathId)

dim xConnect as object
for each xConnect in ActiveWorkbook.Connections
xConnect.delete
Next xConnect

Next Cell
```

Comment: That's not really a question Dan. Also, the code you've supplied doesn't actually loop through any cells either. Rewrite your question and include all the code that is pertinent to your question.

Comment: @CLR Thanks, now revised

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using the Close method for the connection. You might also want to look into opening the connection once at the beginning, sending multiple sql commands, and closing it at the end. A quick examples is included below

```
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.RecordSet
Dim ConnectionString As String

cnn.Open ConnectionString

For .....
    Set rst = cnn.Execute( Insert SQL String here )
      do things
Next .....

rst.Close
cnn.Close
```

Edit: After Dan's comment, here is another way that will open and close the entire connection every time

```
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.RecordSet
Dim ConnectionString As String

For .....
    cnn.Open ConnectionString
    Set rst = cnn.Execute( Insert SQL String here )
      do things
    rst.Close
    cnn.Close
Next .....
```

Comment: I have tried this and it closes the connection. However when it goes to the next cell in the loop I get an error stating the record set has been deleted. I don't understand why it wont create a new connection for each cell in the loop, do something then close the connection and continue to the next cell

Comment: You could try putting all of the ADODB commands inside the for loop if you want to do it that way. Just move the cnn.Open, rst.Close, and cnn.Close inside the for loop. Then it will open and close the entire connection for every cell. I will update the answer for this method.

Comment: Thank you, I thought I tried this it appears I got the order wrong.